# How can checking the return of a java function change the action the function performs?

Tags: java, bukkit

Why would the function safeBreak() perform as expected in Call 1, but not in Call 2 or Call 2.1?

I'm working on my Minecraft Bukkit plugin [ToolBelt](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/toolbelt/).

One of the tools (PickHax) in my plugin allows the player to delete a block while holding a defined material (default DIAMOND_PICKAXE). To provide the widest possible support for other plugins that provide region protection (like WorldGuard) and logging (like HawkEye), I make and call a BlockBreakEvent. Below is the code that does this:

```
protected boolean safeBreak(Block target, Player subject, boolean applyPhysics) {
        BlockBreakEvent canBreak = new BlockBreakEvent(target,subject);
        server.getPluginManager().callEvent(canBreak);
        if(!canBreak.isCancelled())
                target.setTypeId(0, applyPhysics);
        return !canBreak.isCancelled();
}
```

With the current release (0.1) of ToolBelt, this works quite well, and doesn't remove a block if the player doesn't have permission for that region of the server (WorldGuard). I simply set the target [Block](http://jd.bukkit.org/apidocs/org/bukkit/block/Block.html) to the `event.getClickedBlock()`, the subject [Player](http://jd.bukkit.org/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html) to `event.getPlayer()`, and the physics Boolean to `true` if they left-clicked, and `false` if they right-clicked. Here is the call in version 0.1:

**Call 1**

```
safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics);
```

I'm currently working on a new version that supports ranged block deletion. Depending of whether the user is crouching and has the range permission node, the target Block is set by `event.getClickedBlock()` or `subject.getTargetBlock(null,25)`. This works fine except for in one case.

- **case 1**: If they actually clicked on the block (LEFT_CLICK_BLOCK / RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK), they see the change, with either physics settings.
- **case 2**: If they acquired the block at range, and have physics to `true` (LEFT_CLICK_AIR), then they see the change.
- **case 3**: However, if they acquired the block at range, and have physics to `false` (RIGHT_CLICK_AIR), then they do **not** see a block update on the client. If they log off and back on, the change is visible, so the change does happen server side.

To alleviate this issue, I tried to use `subject.sendBlockChange()`, which is supposed to send a fake block change to the user, and not modify the server in any way. With this the user always sees what they have done. Thus the new code:

**Call 2**

```
if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics))
    subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
```

However, for some reason, the change between just running `safeBreak()` and running `if(safeBreak()) sendBlockChange()` makes it so that the region protection (WorldGuard) is not respected. The user gets a printout from WorldGuard still warning them they don't have build rights, but the bock still gets broken.

Just in-case the description for `.sendBlockChange()` was not accurate about it not actually changing the world in any way, I have also tried it with a "harmless" print message

**Call 2.1**

```
if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics))
    subject.sendMessage("Error still present?");
```

When I run Call 2.1, if I am in a region where I have permission to break blocks, I get the "Error still present?" message, but when I'm in a restricted area, I do not. This means that `safeBreak()` is returning the correct value for if I should have broken a block or not, but somehow is still breaking the block. Also, because it doesn't have `.sendBlockChange()` of Call 2, I get the case 3 issue again.

**Call 3**

```
if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics)) {}
```

Now the code has no action other then checking the return value of `safeBreak()`, and yet it still breaks blocks in the restricted area. I switched to Call 1 and it didn't break the blocks in the restricted area.

This brings me back to the original question. I can recompile the ToolBelt.jar with the only difference being Call 1 vs Call 2 and reproduce the issue reliably. If Call 1 is in place, region support is respected, but case 3 doesn't update the client. If Call 2 is in place, the client always gets the block update, but they can remove blocks in any region.

I can route around the issue by not allowing case 3 (no physics removal at range) and using Call 1, however I would like not to compromise the tools ability. Does anyone have any idea why Call 2 and Call 2.1 don't work with regions when Call 1 does without issue?

Documentation links of interest:

- [Block](http://jd.bukkit.org/apidocs/org/bukkit/block/Block.html) : Represents a block. This is a live object, and only one Block may exist for any given location in a world.
- [Player](http://jd.bukkit.org/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html) : Represents a player, connected or not
- [.isCanceled()](http://jd.bukkit.org/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockBreakEvent.html#isCancelled%28%29) : Gets the cancellation state of this event. A canceled event will not be executed in the server, but will still pass to other plugins
- [.sendBlockChange()](http://jd.bukkit.org/apidocs/org/bukkit/entity/Player.html#sendBlockChange%28org.bukkit.Location,%20org.bukkit.Material,%20byte%29) : Send a block change. This fakes a block change packet for a user at a certain location. This will not actually change the world in any way.

Comment: Can you narrow it down a little? http://sscce.org/

Comment: If I call safeBreak without looking at the return value, (safebreak();), then it does not break the block (setType = 0) when a region plugin stops the event (.isCanceled() == true).

If I call setBreak in an if() statement, then even if a region plugin stops the event the the block is still broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was at a level higher then I posted. Sorry for not including enough data. The original Case 1 call was:

```
if(isUseEvent())
    safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics);
else {
    target.setTypeId(0,physics);
    subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
}
```

The Case 2 call was

```
if(isUseEvent())
    if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics))
        subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
else {
    target.setTypeId(0,physics);
    subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
}
```

However, because I didn't wrap the `if(safeBreak()) doStuff;` in {}, it meant that the else lined up with the innermost `if()` statement. Thus proper formatting would show:

```
if(isUseEvent())
    if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics))
        subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
    else {
        target.setTypeId(0,physics);
        subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
    }
```

This can be simply resolved by not taking a stupid shortcut and properly wrapping my `if() {doStuff;}`

```
if(isUseEvent()) {
    if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics)) {
        subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
    }
}else {
    target.setTypeId(0,physics);
    subject.sendBlockChange(target.getLocation(), 0, (byte)0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking an [l-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29) has no effect on the code which generated the l-value. This means the code in the "then" section of your if statement is likely the culprit.

Depending on how the third-party code you're integrating with is designed, things like exceptions might be causing rollback-like behavior.

try using a simple statement in your if block (rather than the "harmless print message") and you should be able to validate this yourself:

```
if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics))
{
}
```

Comment: I have tested this now with a new Call 3 [if(safeBreak(target,event.getPlayer(),physics)) {}] As with Call 2/2.1, it broke the block in the restricted area. I switched the code back to Call 1 and it didn't break blocks in the restricted area.

Comment: There are too many moving pieces for us to diagnose your specific issue. I was merely stating that there is no difference between `foo()` and `if(foo()) {}` (assuming foo returns a boolean)

Comment: I agree there are too many moving parts. However, `safeBreak();` and `if(safeBreak()) {}` are behaving differently, which is the crux of my problem here. I have no change to my code other then Call 1 and Call 3